# Passing a list of string as query parameter to http.get in angular

Tags: angular, http

I have a get method in my API which recieves a ID on the path and a list of date's as query parameters, my http service retrieves me this error

```
public ObterSimulacao<T>(inscricao:string,listaDatas: HttpParams){
    return this.http.get<T>('http://localhost:50441/api/v1/Movimento/Simulacao' + inscricao ,{listaDatas});
}
ERROR in src/app/Data.service.ts(34,95): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ listaDatas: HttpParams; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'listaDatas' does not exist in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
```

I also tried to set listaDatas as :any and as :string[], gets me the same error, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried return this.http.get<T>('http://localhost:50441/api/v1/Movimento/Simulacao' + inscricao ,listaDatas);

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObterSimulacao<T>(inscricao:string,listaDatas: string){
    let params = new HttpParams()
    .append('listDate',listaDatas)
    return this.http.get<T>('http://localhost:50441/api/v1/Movimento/Simulacao/' + inscricao ,{params});
}
```

got it working with this

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the brackets in your request you get :

```
public ObterSimulacao<T>(inscricao:string,listaDatas: HttpParams){
    return this.http.get<T>('http://localhost:50441/api/v1/Movimento/Simulacao' + inscricao , listaDatas);
}
```

all the arguments in the brackets need to be link to a key.
For exemple if you want to have an header you do :

```
return this.http.get<T>('http://localhost:50441/api/v1/Movimento/Simulacao' + inscricao , listaDatas, {headers: yourHeader});
```

hope it helps